# How to allow special characteres (portuguese) in colnames R

Tags: r, dplyr

What is the easiest way to allow special characters ("'", "ç") in the column names of my dataframes without renaming columns by index as I have done below:

```
rais2011_licmat = rais2011_licmat %>% rename(rais2011_licmat[1] = vínculo_ativo, rais2011_licmat[5] = mês_desligamento)
```

the column names that have "ç" and graphical accents look like this and I would like to allow special characters of Brazilian Portuguese

```
> colnames(rais2011_licmat)

 [1] "V<ed>nculoAtivo3112"      
 [2] "CausaAfastamento1"        
 [3] "QtdDiasAfastamento"       
 [4] "MotivoDesligamento"       
 [5] "M<ea>sDesligamento"       
 [6] "Escolaridadeap<f3>s2005"  
 [7] "Ra<e7>aCor"
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is an encoding problem, try setting the encoding argument in your import function to "utf-8" or "latin-1". And I do not recommend special characters in variables names

Comment: I am also from Brazil, so I also deal a lot with this problem, a tip would be the function `clean_names` form the package `janitor`

Comment: Hi, Mariana. this is most likely an encoding issue. See the first comment by Vinicius. 
Eu mesmo ja fiz essa pergunta no SO em portugues e apanhei muito ate conseguir fazer dar certo ;-)

Comment: Try to call this before importing the data, it may help: `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", 'pt_BR.UTF-8')`

Comment: You didn't say what platform you are working on, but I'd guess Windows.  In Windows R, non-ASCII names are not supported unless they can be represented in the local encoding.  How is your locale set?  (Run `Sys.getlocale()` to see.)